# How do I submit a Google Form (Or add a submission to the form's data) from an external program?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-forms, google-workspace

I'm making a website with an organization, and we use Google Sheets for the majority of our backend management because it's what's most accessible for our users. We use Google Forms for submitting data to our sheets, and I'd like this website to be able to submit data as well.

I have full access to both the Forms and the Sheets in question, but I can't figure out how to put a submission into the form's data.

I found this as the closest thing to an answer I've been able to find:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/importing-data-into-a-google-forms-response-sheet/154041#154041

The issue, however, is that while this solution does allow me to add responses to a form's data, it needs to be in Google Workspace, which my website is not. I've edited Spreadsheets in the past with Google's API and a client, but the methods used in the above solution aren't accessible via Google's Forms API as far as I can tell.

Naturally, the next thing I looked into was initiating a Google Workspace program externally. I found Google Web Apps, but it seems like those can only be embedded in Google Sites, which once again, my website is not.

Comment: maybe you can simply copy the data in form sheet to another that you have full control?

Comment: I believe you can call the doPost() or doGet() endpoint from a service account which you can setup with Google Cloud Platform Project.  You can pass parameters to the endpoint function via the querystring.

Comment: @Cooper I have a service account set up because I've edited Spreadsheets with them, but it directly used the Google Sheets API for that. Can a service account send getPosts? I thought those were event triggers, but I'll look into them a bit more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I mostly just use the GET method but I think the answer is that you can use both GET and POST